# Java: Text Field FocusListener focusGained executes two times, why?

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtextfield, focuslistener

I have a text box and I would like to show a dialog box when text box is focus gain. So I wrote following codes. But when dialog box disposed the dialog box appears again. I tried to debug and check with line break. That time it does not execute multiple time but in normal mode it executes multiple time so dialog box appears two times...

```
txt1.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {

        myform f = new myform(null,true);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        if("OK".equals(f.button_state)){
            txt2.requestFocus();   
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {                
    }

});
```

If I place the `txt2.requestFocus()` before the dialog box visible then multiple execution does not happen. But I am not convinced. Because I required to keep the cursor in `txt1`.

Have you any idea..>

Answer (score 0):

- FocusListener isn't proper place for code where is created of modifyied container
- Focus is quite asynchronous, then there any some guarantee with proper ordering of methods
- Swing GUI creations must be wrapped into invokeLater, more see in Oracle tutorial - Initial Thread
- only this code snipped will be works in FocusListener

. wrapped into invokeLater

```
if("OK".equals(f.button_state)){
     txt2.requestFocus();   
}
```

- or `setVisible(true);` for `myform` wrapped into `invokLater`, but I think that must be prepared before (every `JComponents` are added, initialized, used and applied `LayoutManager`, `packed`), otherwise nothing guarantee anything, there you can call only

. wrapped into invokeLater

```
f.setVisible(true);
if("OK".equals(f.button_state)){
      txt2.requestFocus();   
}
```